# how to animate `a:hover::before` color

Tags: html, css

I add a different color to anchor element, when hovered, then I add an animation to the color. However it does not animate. 
Is there anything wrong with my code?
The codepen is [here](http://codepen.io/xg-wang/pen/VmzERW).

```css
@import url('http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

.social-buttons a::before {
    font-family: 'Fontawesome';
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    content: '\f08e';
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #888;
    animation: color .5s ease-in-out;
}
.social-buttons a:hover::before {
    color: #0275d8;
    animation: color .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <h4>Around the Web</h4>
  <div class="social-buttons">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/xingan-wang"><span class="sr-only">Linkedin</span></a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/"><span class="sr-only">Github</span></a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/"><span class="sr-only">Facebook</span></a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/"><span class="sr-only">Twitter</span></a>
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: Where is your `animation`? Or did you mean to put `transition` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you were looking for [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) instead and not animation.

```css
@import url('http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

.social-buttons a::before {
    font-family: 'Fontawesome';
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    content: '\f08e';
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #888;
    transition: color .5s ease-in-out;
}
.social-buttons a:hover::before {
    color: #0275d8;
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <h4>Around the Web</h4>
  <div class="social-buttons">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/xingan-wang"><span class="sr-only">Linkedin</span></a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/"><span class="sr-only">Github</span></a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/"><span class="sr-only">Facebook</span></a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/"><span class="sr-only">Twitter</span></a>
  </div>
</div
```